Why is the matrix transposed when calculating the gradient in a multiple linear regression?
I am taking an online machine learning course and when talking about multivariable linear regression they used the following function to calculate the gradient:
def gradient(X, Y, w):
   return 2 * np.matmul(X.T, (predict(X, w) - Y)) / X.shape[0]

X is a matrix with the data, Y is a single column matrix with the results and w is a single column matrix with the weights. predict(W, w) returns the model's prediction with the current weights and it has the same format as Y.
I am familiar with the idea of using the partial derivative of the function to find how close the model is from the local minimum for that weight, but i can't grasp on why do I need the X matrix to be in transposed form to make this calculations. Could I just calculate each partial derivative and use it as the individual gradients?
